# azure custom vision model precision

Tags: azure, machine-learning, azure-cognitive-services, azure-machine-learning-service

Im having problems in identifying  the best way to optimize the custom vision model.

1. In using Image classification, will labeling the same image with different label at different time effect the precision of machine learning? 
   //for example labeling and training image A today with the label 't-shirt', labeling and training image A tomorrow with the label 'blue'.
   //We are basically trying to input one classification at a time with the same image (total of five classification, such as style and color) and wanted to know whether this way will effect the prediction precision.
2. Will labeling larger amount of data at once when inputing the image for machine learning increase the precision of the model? (for example, will there be any difference between 50 label and 100 label for an image to learn at a time?)
3. Is there any way to teach machine learning to identify object recognition using the result gained from the image classification, else can i teach image classification and object recognition separately with the same type of image?
4. Will running the learning process of the machine learning longer (for example, the difference between 1hour and 10hours) always give better results?

Comment: May I ask about that after you update the tag of Image, did you Train the image again?